# Best Antivirus for Workstation today

Tags: anti-virus

would you tell me 3 antivirus programs and put them into TOP 3 list? Should i take Kaspersky, AVG, Avast, McAfee or Symantec? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays, its a subjective question. Subjective as it is, I am going to answer it: I prefer Kaspersky. I've had very pleasant experience with it in the past, it features excellent registry/behavioural monitoring facilities, the response time of the support lightning quick (you could submit a sample, that's not in the signature db and it would be in the updates within an hour, usually even quicker).

By the way. Antivirus tests mean nothing. At all.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently used AVG, but the more recent versions have veered towards bloatware.  I would suggest something along the lines of ClamAV, NOD32, or Kapersky.

Comment: +1 to ClamAV for not dragging system performance down as much as a lot of the others.